# Very basic use of self.view.backgroundcolor

Tags: objective-c

I have the array:

```
self.colors = @[@"redColor",
                    @"blueColor",
                    ];
```

And then the function:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor [[self.colors[1] ] ];
```

When I put:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

It works immediately. This isn't working 'expected identifier'
Can't I use a variable inside the `backgroundcolor` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redColor` and `blueColor` are methods from within the `UIColor` class, that return a `UIColor*`.

There are no methods for the class `UIColor` that receive a string representing a color, and return a `UIColor*`.

If you want it to work the way you described, form an array of UIColors and not Strings:

```
self.colors = @[[UIColor redColor],
                [UIColor blueColor]
                ];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing strings in your array. If you want to store color objects change the code to the following:

```
self.colors = @[[UIColor redColor],
    [UIColor blueColor],
];
```

And then you can do

```
self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[1];
```

Comment: Or if you really want to have an array of strings you can do `[UIColor performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"redColor")]`

Comment: Yes, there is always performSelector :) but what happens when name is not from one built-in colors?

Comment: Well there is always `if( [UIColor respondsToSelector: ...] )` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood what is returned from `self.colors[1]` There are a couple of ways that you can do this I will start with the code you already have.

So we have:

```
// Our array of colors as strings
self.colors = @[@"redColor", @"blueColor", etc];

// Because our colors are strings we need to use NSSelectorFromString to convert 
// the string to a selector
SEL colorSelector = NSSelectorFromString(self.colors[1]);
// Then we need to check if colorSelector actually responds to UIColor
if([UIColor respondsToSelector:colorSelector]) {
    // If the if statement is true then we are good to set the color with it
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor performSelector:colorSelector];
}
```

Or as others have already said and which would probably be better you could do

```
self.colors = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor blueColor]];

self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[1];
```